# Byte to ASCII turns into square characters

Tags: c++, usb, ascii

I have an USB Device. It's a pedometer/activity tracker.
I'm able to send bytes to the device and I'm also able to retrieve bytes back.
But for some reason numbers are turned into those square characters and not into numbers... The characters that are actually letters come through just fine.
Any idea's on how to retrieve the bytes as numbers?

The expected format something like this:
[image]

[image]

Comment: What do you expect? There isn´t an beautiful char for *every* number, only for some.

Comment: @deviantfan If he expects a numeric and a square pop ups? isn't the question valid then?

Answer (score 1):

The square characters are actually binary data, likely hex before 0x20 or above 0x7f.

The first 15 bytes are binary, you would need to interpret them using something approximately like the following pseudocode:

```
if (isascii(byte)) {
  textToAppendToEditBox(byte);
} else {
  textToAppendToEditBox( someKindOfSprintF( "{%02x}");
}
```

There are plenty of googleable examples of hex dumping code snippets that can make it look pretty

Answer (score 0):

The expected format that you showed sends binary data.  You first have to convert the received data to internal information, then you can pass that information to an `std::ostringstream` to display it in a gui.

When reading in the binary data, make sure to respect the used endianess.